# build project without runtimes folder but included nuget packages in nopcommerce 4.40(.net 5 and VS 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-5, nopcommerce

I'm developing plugin for nopcommerce,

I'm using VS 2019 and nopcommerce 4.40.4(.net 5)

I should use a nuget package in my plugin,

If I set **CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies** to **true**, when I build my project, it created runtimes folder, which is about 65 MB,

If I set **CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies** to **false**, it does not create runtimes folder, but, the dll of nuget package which I should use, not included in the build folder,

would you please help me about this?

*Note: set **copy local** to **no**, make no difference when I change for Nop.Services which I use in the project*

this is my csproj and my the package is > SmsIrRestful.NetCore :

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\AttributeStockSMS</OutputPath>
    <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
    <!--Set this parameter to true to get the dlls copied from the NuGet cache to the output of your project.
    You need to set this parameter to true if your plugin has a nuget package 
    to ensure that the dlls copied from the NuGet cache to the output of your project-->
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>false</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClearPluginAssemblies Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="plugin.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="plugin.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SmsIrRestful.NetCore" Version="1.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Libraries\Nop.Services\Nop.Services.csproj">
      <Private>false</Private>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="NopTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
    <!-- Delete unnecessary libraries from plugins path -->
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ClearPluginAssemblies)" Properties="PluginPath=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutDir)" Targets="NopClear" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using NuGet reference, include the dll file of that NuGet package. For example, You are going to use [TaxJar](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaxJar/) library then follow these steps.

1. Added NuGet reference.
   [image]
2. Right click on NuGet package and go to properties.
   [image]
3. Copy path value from property values as below.
   [image]
4. Go to that path in file explorer.
   [image]
5. Find dll file(s) from there, copy-paste into your plugin folder and add refence.
   [image]
6. Repeat same procedures for dependent packages also (if any).
   [image]
7. Mark as **Copy Local** to **Yes** from properties.
   [image]

Comment: I did it, but after build, it didn't copy the dll to output plugin folder, I don't know why !

Comment: Paste the dll files into the root folder of your plugin source code (as you can see in 7). Right click on dll, go to properties and set copy to output directory equal `true`

Comment: It doesn't have that option :( : https://pasteboard.co/Khlhka2.jpg

Comment: Click on the dll, not on dll reference.